# Disable a move down in Google Charts Treemap

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, treemap

I am using the Google-Charts Treemap to display a very large number of nodes. The default behavior is to move down the tree when a user left-clicks a node and to move back up the tree when a user right-clicks the graph.
The right-clicks redraw the chart for each click. The redraw is very slow because of the large number of nodes.
How to disable the node move down function without disabling the mouse click event?
How to improve  the performance of treemap draw?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the **node move down function** occurs when a chart element is selected

to **disable**, clear the selection when the `'select'` event fires

`tree.setSelection([]);`

this will prevent the chart from displaying the next level down...

---

please see the following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['treemap']
});

function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'ID');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Parent');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Number Of Lines');
  data.addRows([
    ['Shakespeare', null, 0],

    ['Comedies', 'Shakespeare', null],
    ['Tragedies', 'Shakespeare', null],
    ['Histories', 'Shakespeare', null],

    ['As You Like It', 'Comedies', null],
    ['Adam', 'As You Like It', 10],
    ['Amiens', 'As You Like It', 10],
    ['Audrey', 'As You Like It', 12],
    ['Celia', 'As You Like It', 108],
    ['Charles', 'As You Like It', 8],
    ['Corin', 'As You Like It', 24],
    ['Dennis', 'As You Like It', 2],
    ['Duke', 'As You Like It', 32],
    ['Frederick', 'As You Like It', 20],
    ['Hymen', 'As You Like It', 1],
    ['Jaques (lord)', 'As You Like It', 57],
    ['Jaques (son)', 'As You Like It', 2],
    ['Le Beau', 'As You Like It', 14],
    ['Oliver', 'As You Like It', 37],
    ['Orlando', 'As You Like It', 120],
    ['Phebe', 'As You Like It', 23],
    ['Rosalind', 'As You Like It', 201],
    ['Silvius', 'As You Like It', 24],
    ['Sir Oliver Martext', 'As You Like It', 3],
    ['Touchstone', 'As You Like It', 74],
    ['William', 'As You Like It', 11],

    ['Comedy Of Errors', 'Comedies', null],
    ['Adriana', 'Comedy Of Errors', 79],
    ['Aegeon', 'Comedy Of Errors', 17],
    ['Aemilia', 'Comedy Of Errors', 16],
    ['Angelo', 'Comedy Of Errors', 31],
    ['Antipholus of Ephesus', 'Comedy Of Errors', 76],
    ['Antipholus of Syracuse', 'Comedy Of Errors', 103],
    ['Balthazar', 'Comedy Of Errors', 5],
    ['Courtezan', 'Comedy Of Errors', 11],
    ['Dromio of Ephesus', 'Comedy Of Errors', 63],
    ['Dromio of Syracuse', 'Comedy Of Errors', 99],
    ['Luce', 'Comedy Of Errors', 7],
    ['Luciana', 'Comedy Of Errors', 43],
    ['Pinch', 'Comedy Of Errors', 6],
    ['Solinus', 'Comedy Of Errors', 22],

    ['Merchant Of Venice', 'Comedies', null],
    ['Antonio', 'Merchant Of Venice', 47],
    ['Balthasar', 'Merchant Of Venice', 1],
    ['Bassanio', 'Merchant Of Venice', 73],
    ['Duke (of Venice)', 'Merchant Of Venice', 18],
    ['Gratiano', 'Merchant Of Venice', 48],
    ['Jessica', 'Merchant Of Venice', 26],
    ['Launcelot Gobbo', 'Merchant Of Venice', 44],
    ['Leonardo', 'Merchant Of Venice', 2],
    ['Lorenzo', 'Merchant Of Venice', 47],
    ['Nerissa', 'Merchant Of Venice', 36],
    ['Old Gobbo', 'Merchant Of Venice', 19],
    ['Portia', 'Merchant Of Venice', 117],
    ['Prince of Arragon', 'Merchant Of Venice', 4],
    ['Prince of Morocco', 'Merchant Of Venice', 7],
    ['Salanio', 'Merchant Of Venice', 18],
    ['Salarino', 'Merchant Of Venice', 27],
    ['Salerio', 'Merchant Of Venice', 6],
    ['Shylock', 'Merchant Of Venice', 79],
    ['Stephano', 'Merchant Of Venice', 3],
    ['Tubal', 'Merchant Of Venice', 8],

    ['Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 'Comedies', null],
    ['Bottom', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 59],
    ['Cobweb', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 4],
    ['Demetrius', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 48],
    ['Egeus', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 7],
    ['Fairy', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 4],
    ['Flute', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 18],
    ['Helena', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 36],
    ['Hermia', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 48],
    ['Hippolyta', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 14],
    ['Lysander', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 50],
    ['Moth', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 2],
    ['Mustardseed', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 5],
    ['Oberon', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 29],
    ['Peaseblossom', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 4],
    ['Philostrate', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 6],
    ['Puck', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 33],
    ['Quince', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 40],
    ['Snout', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 9],
    ['Snug', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 4],
    ['Starveling', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 7],
    ['Theseus', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 48],
    ['Titania', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 23],

    ['Taming Of The Shrew', 'Comedies', null],
    ['Baptista Minola', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 68],
    ['Bianca', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 29],
    ['Biondello', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 39],
    ['Christopher Sly', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 24],
    ['Curtis', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 20],
    ['Gremio', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 58],
    ['Grumio', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 63],
    ['Haberdasher', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 1],
    ['Hortensio', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 70],
    ['Joseph',  'Taming Of The Shrew', 1],
    ['Katherina', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 82],
    ['Lucentio',  'Taming Of The Shrew', 61],
    ['Nathaniel', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 4],
    ['Nicholas', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 1],
    ['Peter',  'Taming Of The Shrew', 2],
    ['Petruchio', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 158],
    ['Philip',  'Taming Of The Shrew', 1],
    ['Tranio', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 90],
    ['Vincentio', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 23],

    ['The Tempest', 'Comedies', null],
    ['Adrian', 'The Tempest', 9],
    ['Alonso', 'The Tempest', 40],
    ['Antonio, duke of Milan', 'The Tempest', 57],
    ['Ariel', 'The Tempest', 45],
    ['Caliban', 'The Tempest', 50],
    ['Ceres', 'The Tempest', 4],
    ['Ferdinand', 'The Tempest', 31],
    ['Francisco', 'The Tempest', 2],
    ['Gonzalo', 'The Tempest', 52],
    ['Iris', 'The Tempest', 4],
    ['Juno', 'The Tempest', 2],
    ['Master', 'The Tempest', 2],
    ['Miranda', 'The Tempest', 50],
    ['Nymphs', 'The Tempest', 0],
    ['Prospero', 'The Tempest', 114],
    ['Reapers', 'The Tempest', 0],
    ['Sebastian', 'The Tempest', 67],
    ['Stephano (Servant to Portia)', 'The Tempest', 60],
    ['Trinculo', 'The Tempest', 39],

    ['Henry VIII', 'Histories', null],
    ['Anne Bullen', 'Henry VIII', 18],
    ['Archbishop Cranmer', 'Henry VIII', 21],
    ['Bishop Lincoln', 'Henry VIII', 2],
    ['Brandon', 'Henry VIII', 6],
    ['Capucius', 'Henry VIII', 5],
    ['Cardinal Campeius', 'Henry VIII', 14],
    ['Cardinal Wolsey', 'Henry VIII', 79],
    ['Cromwell', 'Henry VIII', 21],
    ['Doctor Butts', 'Henry VIII', 4],
    ['Duke of Buckingham', 'Henry VIII', 26],
    ['Duke of Norfolk', 'Henry VIII', 48],
    ['Duke of Suffolk', 'Henry VIII', 30],
    ['Earl of Surrey', 'Henry VIII', 24],
    ['First Secretary to Wolsey', 'Henry VIII', 2],
    ['Gardiner', 'Henry VIII', 22],
    ['Garter', 'Henry VIII', 1],
    ['Griffith', 'Henry VIII', 13],
    ['King Henry VIII', 'Henry VIII', 81],
    ['Lord Abergavenny', 'Henry VIII', 5],
    ['Lord Chamberlain', 'Henry VIII', 38],
    ['Lord Chancellor', 'Henry VIII', 7],
    ['Lord Sands', 'Henry VIII', 17],
    ['Old Lady', 'Henry VIII', 14],
    ['Patience', 'Henry VIII', 3],
    ['Porter (door-keeper of the Council-chamber)', 'Henry VIII', 10],
    ['Queen Katharine', 'Henry VIII', 50],
    ['Sir Anthony Denny', 'Henry VIII', 3],
    ['Sir Henry Guildford', 'Henry VIII', 1],
    ['Sir Nicholas Vaux', 'Henry VIII', 1],
    ['Sir Thomas Lovell', 'Henry VIII', 21],
    ['Surveyor to the Duke of Buckingham', 'Henry VIII', 9],

    ['History Of King John', 'Histories', null],
    ['Arthur Duke of Bretagne', 'History Of King John', 23],
    ['Blanch', 'History Of King John', 9],
    ['Cardinal Pandulph', 'History Of King John', 23],
    ['Chatillon', 'History Of King John', 5],
    ['Constance', 'History Of King John', 36],
    ['Essex', 'History Of King John', 1],
    ['Faulconbridge', 'History Of King John', 4],
    ['Hubert de Burgh', 'History Of King John', 52],
    ['James Gurney', 'History Of King John', 1],
    ['King John', 'History Of King John', 95],
    ['King Phillip', 'History Of King John', 43],
    ['Lady Faulconbridge', 'History Of King John', 5],
    ['Lewis the Dauphin', 'History Of King John', 29],
    ['Lord Bigot', 'History Of King John', 6],
    ['Lymoges duke of Austria', 'History Of King John', 16],
    ['Melun', 'History Of King John', 3],
    ['Pembroke earl of Pembroke', 'History Of King John', 20],
    ['Peter of Pomfret', 'History Of King John', 1],
    ['Philip the Bastard', 'History Of King John', 89],
    ['Prince Henry', 'History Of King John', 8],
    ['Queen Elinor', 'History Of King John', 22],
    ['Salisbury earl of Salisbury', 'History Of King John', 36],

    ['Antony And Cleopatra', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Agrippa', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 28],
    ['Alexas', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 15],
    ['Antony', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 202],
    ['Canidius', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 10],
    ['Captain', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 1],
    ['Charmian', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 63],
    ['Cleopatra', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 204],
    ['Demetrius (Friend to Antony)', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 2],
    ['Dercetas', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 5],
    ['Diomedes', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 7],
    ['Dolabella', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 23],
    ['Domitius Enobarus', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 113],
    ['Egyptian', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 2],
    ['Eros', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 27],
    ['Euphronius', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 5],
    ['Gallus', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 1],
    ['Iras', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 18],
    ['Lepidus', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 30],
    ['Mardian', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 7],
    ['Mecaenas', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 16],
    ['Menas', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 35],
    ['Menecrates', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 2],
    ['Octavia', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 13],
    ['Octavius', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 98],
    ['Philo', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 2],
    ['Pompey', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 41],
    ['Proculeius', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 10],
    ['Scarus', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 12],
    ['Seleucus', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 3],
    ['Silius', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 3],
    ['Taurus', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 1],
    ['Thyreus', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 12],
    ['Varrius', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 1],
    ['Ventidius', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 4],

    ['Coriolanus', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Aedile', 'Coriolanus', 10],
    ['Cominius', 'Coriolanus', 67],
    ['Coriolanus (Caius Marcius Coriolanus)', 'Coriolanus', 189],
    ['Junius Brutus', 'Coriolanus', 91],
    ['Lieutenant',  'Coriolanus', 4],
    ['Menenius Agrippa',  'Coriolanus', 162],
    ['Patrician', 'Coriolanus', 3],
    ['Roman', 'Coriolanus', 10],
    ['Sicinius Velutus', 'Coriolanus', 117],
    ['Titus Lartius', 'Coriolanus', 23],
    ['Tullus Aufidius', 'Coriolanus', 45],
    ['Valeria', 'Coriolanus', 14],
    ['Virgilia', 'Coriolanus', 26],
    ['Volsce', 'Coriolanus', 9],
    ['Volumnia',  'Coriolanus', 57],
    ['Young Coriolanus', 'Coriolanus', 1],

    ['Cymbeline', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Arviragus', 'Cymbeline', 46],
    ['Belarius', 'Cymbeline', 58],
    ['Caius Lucius', 'Cymbeline', 25],
    ['Cloten',  'Cymbeline', 77],
    ['Cornelius (physician)', 'Cymbeline', 13],
    ['Cymbeline, King of Britain', 'Cymbeline', 81],
    ['Guiderius', 'Cymbeline', 62],
    ['Helen',  'Cymbeline', 0],
    ['Iachimo', 'Cymbeline', 77],
    ['Imogen',  'Cymbeline', 118],
    ['Jupiter', 'Cymbeline', 1],
    ['Philario', 'Cymbeline', 14],
    ['Pisanio',  'Cymbeline', 58],
    ['Posthumus Leonatus', 'Cymbeline', 77],
    ['Queen',  'Cymbeline', 27],
    ['Roman Captain', 'Cymbeline', 4],
    ['Sicilius Leonatus', 'Cymbeline', 7],

    ['The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Bernardo', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 19],
    ['Claudius, King of Denmark', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 102],
    ['Cornelius', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 1],
    ['Father\'s Ghost', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 15],
    ['Fortinbras', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 6],
    ['Francisco ', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 8],
    ['Gertrude', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 69],
    ['Guildenstern', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 29],
    ['Hamlet', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 358],
    ['Horatio', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 109],
    ['Laertes', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 62],
    ['Lucianus', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 0],
    ['Marcellus', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 37],
    ['Ophelia', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 58],
    ['Osric', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 25],
    ['Polonius', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 86],
    ['Reynaldo', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 13],
    ['Rosencrantz', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 48],
    ['Voltemand', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 1],

    ['Julius Caesar', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Antony (Marcus Antonius)', 'Julius Caesar', 51],
    ['Artemidorus of Cnidos', 'Julius Caesar', 4],
    ['Brutus (Marcus Brutus)', 'Julius Caesar', 194],
    ['Caesar (Julius Caesar)', 'Julius Caesar', 42],
    ['Calpurnia', 'Julius Caesar', 6],
    ['Casca', 'Julius Caesar', 39],
    ['Cassius', 'Julius Caesar', 140],
    ['Cicero', 'Julius Caesar', 4],
    ['Cinna', 'Julius Caesar', 11],
    ['Cinna the Poet', 'Julius Caesar', 8],
    ['Claudius', 'Julius Caesar', 2],
    ['Clitus', 'Julius Caesar', 8],
    ['Dardanius', 'Julius Caesar', 3],
    ['Decius Brutus', 'Julius Caesar', 12],
    ['Flavius', 'Julius Caesar', 5],
    ['Lepidus (Marcus Antonius Lepidus)', 'Julius Caesar', 3],
    ['Ligarius', 'Julius Caesar', 5],
    ['Lucilius', 'Julius Caesar', 10],
    ['Lucius', 'Julius Caesar', 24],
    ['Marullus', 'Julius Caesar', 6],
    ['Messala', 'Julius Caesar', 20],
    ['Metellus Cimber', 'Julius Caesar', 5],
    ['Octavius (Octavius Caesar)', 'Julius Caesar', 19],
    ['Pindarus', 'Julius Caesar', 5],
    ['Popilius (Popilius Lena)', 'Julius Caesar', 2],
    ['Portia (wife of Brutus)', 'Julius Caesar', 16],
    ['Publius', 'Julius Caesar', 2],
    ['Strato', 'Julius Caesar', 4],
    ['Tintinius', 'Julius Caesar', 10],
    ['Trebonius', 'Julius Caesar', 4],
    ['Varro', 'Julius Caesar', 6],
    ['Volumnius', 'Julius Caesar', 3],
    ['Young Cato', 'Julius Caesar', 3],

    ['King Lear', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Cordelia',  'King Lear', 31],
    ['Curan',  'King Lear', 4],
    ['Duke of Albany', 'King Lear', 58],
    ['Duke of Burgundy', 'King Lear', 5],
    ['Duke of Cornwall', 'King Lear', 53],
    ['Earl of Gloucester', 'King Lear', 118],
    ['Earl of Kent', 'King Lear', 127],
    ['Edgar',  'King Lear', 98],
    ['Edmund', 'King Lear', 79],
    ['Goneril', 'King Lear', 53],
    ['King of France', 'King Lear', 5],
    ['Lear', 'King Lear', 188],
    ['Oswald', 'King Lear', 38],
    ['Regan',  'King Lear', 73],

    ['The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Angus', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 4],
    ['Banquo', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 33],
    ['Caithness', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 3],
    ['Donalbain', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 3],
    ['Duncan', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 18],
    ['Fleance', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 2],
    ['Hecate', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 2],
    ['Lady Macbeth', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 59],
    ['Lady Macduff', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 19],
    ['Lennox', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 21],
    ['Macbeth', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 146],
    ['Macduff', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 59],
    ['Malcolm', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 40],
    ['Menteith', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 5],
    ['Porter', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 4],
    ['Ross', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 39],
    ['Seyton', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 5],
    ['Siward', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 11],
    ['Son (Macduff\'s son)', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 14],
    ['Young Siward', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 4],

    ['The Tragedy Of Othello', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Bianca (Mistress to Cassio)', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 15],
    ['Brabantio', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 30],
    ['Cassio', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 110],
    ['Desdemona', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 165],
    ['Duke of Venice', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 25],
    ['Emilia', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 103],
    ['Gratiano (Brother to Brabantio)', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 20],
    ['Iago', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 272],
    ['Lodovico', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 33],
    ['Montano', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 24],
    ['Othello', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 274],
    ['Roderigo', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 59],

    ['Romeo And Juliet', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Abraham', 'Romeo And Juliet', 5],
    ['Balthasar (Servant to Romeo)', 'Romeo And Juliet', 12],
    ['Benvolio', 'Romeo And Juliet', 64],
    ['Capulet', 'Romeo And Juliet', 51],
    ['Friar John', 'Romeo And Juliet', 4],
    ['Friar Laurence', 'Romeo And Juliet', 55],
    ['Gregory', 'Romeo And Juliet', 15],
    ['Juliet', 'Romeo And Juliet', 118],
    ['Lady Capulet', 'Romeo And Juliet', 45],
    ['Lady Montague', 'Romeo And Juliet', 2],
    ['Mercutio', 'Romeo And Juliet', 62],
    ['Montague', 'Romeo And Juliet', 10],
    ['Paris', 'Romeo And Juliet', 23],
    ['Peter (Servant to Juliet\'s Nurse)', 'Romeo And Juliet', 13],
    ['Prince Escalus', 'Romeo And Juliet', 16],
    ['Romeo', 'Romeo And Juliet', 163],
    ['Sampson', 'Romeo And Juliet', 20],
    ['Tybalt', 'Romeo And Juliet', 17]
  ]);

  var tree = new google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  var options = {
    highlightOnMouseOver: true,
    maxDepth: 1,
    maxPostDepth: 2,
    minHighlightColor: '#8c6bb1',
    midHighlightColor: '#9ebcda',
    maxHighlightColor: '#edf8fb',
    minColor: '#009688',
    midColor: '#f7f7f7',
    maxColor: '#ee8100',
    headerHeight: 15,
    showScale: true,
    height: 500,
    useWeightedAverageForAggregation: true
  };

  google.visualization.events.addListener(tree, 'select', function () {
    tree.setSelection([]);
  });

  tree.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```