# Changing the select event listener for TreeMap

Tags: google-visualization

By default, [google.visualization.TreeMap](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap) behaves as follows on click:

> The default behavior is to move down the tree when a user left-clicks
>   a node, and to move back up the tree when a user right-clicks the
>   graph

How do I change the behavior to do something else on click? I can see how to add an event listener for the `select` event to do something else, but I can't see how to remove the default behavior of "moving down the tree."

Comment: check this answer --> [Disable a move down in Google Charts Treemap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42181211/5090771)